# Installing python3 and beautifulsoup coding in Xcode to Mac

Tags: python, xcode, macos, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I followed this url from:[https://stringpiggy.hpd.io/mac-osx-python3-dual-install/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q3ua.png) and checked python version.

```
Python --version
>> Python 3.5.2

which python3
>> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3

echo $PATH
>> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I used xcode to compile my code, when I import urllib and return,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 21, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

So I think python IDE is direct to machine default python
    and try `python --version`
    Python 2.7.10
    How can I use Python3 to install beautifulsoup 4.x

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have named your script *python.py* so that is why you are seeing the error:

```
padraic@home:~$ touch python.py
padraic@home:~$ echo "import urllib.request" > python.py 
padraic@home:~$ cat python.py 
import urllib.request
padraic@home:~$ python python.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

Rename your file and delete any .pyc files in the directory.

Comment: Hi @Padraic Cunningham I follow your tip and create a new project but I get an error message from Xcode Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: I don't see any error, the solution above is what was causing your issue, if you have removed the python.pyc and renamed the file that error will be fixed

Comment: I get a message like above

Comment: Then you still have a file named python.py in your path

Comment: But after running I still get the same message like above

Comment: @RoyWu, then you have not done what I have suggested in my answer, *rename the python.py file and delete any  python.pyc

Comment: Sorry! I have been solve my problem, but another problem is that I can't import beautfulsoup4,but I have been already install like above